# Swagger @ApiModel value ignored

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

Using springfox-swagger 2.8.0, we have a POJO in a spring boot application:

```
@ApiModel(value = "Receipt")
public class Receipt {

    @ApiModelProperty(position = 0) 
    private String guid;

    public Receipt(String guid) {
        this.guid = guid;
    }

    public String getGuid() {
        return guid;
    }
}
```

We would expect this to be converted to JSON something like this:

```
"Receipt": {
     "guid":"86f3426c-f200-4bc2-b8e9-e55d6e2c9969"
 }
```

but it is missing the wrapper value and only looks like:

```
{"guid":"86f3426c-f200-4bc2-b8e9-e55d6e2c9969"}
```

EDIT:

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/packages")
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = HypermediaType.HAL)
public class PackageController {
    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Receipt> sendPackage(@RequestBody FooPackage fooPackage) {
        String guid = getGUID();

        // ...

        Receipt receipt = new Receipt(guid);
        BodyBuilder builder = ResponseEntity.ok();
        return builder.body(receipt);
}
```

Comment: how does your controller look like? where are you using this ApiModel

Comment: Please see EDIT